# Windows 7 mouse drag lag

Tags: windows-7, selection, lag, text-cursor

When selecting text or click-and-dragging in *any* app, the selection/scrollbar/item being dragged always lags a few characters behind the cursor when the cursor is moved quickly. It's a slight issue but as someone who does a lot of code/text editing, it's enough to be annoying.

This doesn't happen in the Windows XP installation (dual-booted), or in Windows 7 with Aero disabled. In these cases, the selection always keeps up perfectly with the cursor.

Other than this, W7 doesn't lag at all. In fact, the CPU and GPU don't even budge while selecting text or dragging scrollbars, which seems to indicate that it's not a graphics hardware issue.

Are there configuration/display options that could effect this?

Comment: What language are you using, and does it apply to selecting a row of pictures or icons also?